# Writing binary .stl files in C++

Tags: c++, fstream

I want to write data from an vector of coordinates into a binary .stl 3d geometry file.

I need to have a 80 bit header, 24bit number of triangles.
Each triangle is supposed to be defined by 3 points and one normal, each of which coordinate values is 32 bit.In addition, each triangle may have an attribute, which I wanted to leave empty. (See [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_%28file_format%29) )

I guess I am still having misunderstanding about char and binary mode.

The file that is produced in the end has the same size as my original file but cannot be read by the graphics programme, so there needs to be a logical mistake still...

My point coordinates are  double valued before casting to char*, is this ok to do so??

[image: line out of the binary file]

My code:

```
void write_stl(std::string filename, std::vector<tri> triangles){

    //binary file
    std::string header_info = "solid " + filename + "-output";
    char head[80];
    std::strncpy(head,header_info.c_str(),sizeof(head)-1);
    char attribute[2] = "0";
    unsigned long nTriLong = triangles.size() ;

    std::ofstream myfile;

    myfile.open((Filename + "-out.stl").c_str(),  std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    myfile.write(head,sizeof(head));
    myfile.write((char*)&nTriLong,4);

    //write down every triangle
    for (std::vector<tri>::iterator it = triangles.begin(); it!=triangles.end(); it++){
        //normal vector coordinates

        myfile.write((char*)&it->m_n.m_x, 4);
        myfile.write((char*)&it->m_n.m_y, 4);
        myfile.write((char*)&it->m_n.m_z, 4);

        //p1 coordinates
        myfile.write((char*)&it->m_p1.m_x, 4);
        myfile.write((char*)&it->m_p1.m_y, 4);
        myfile.write((char*)&it->m_p1.m_z, 4);

        //p2 coordinates
        myfile.write((char*)&it->m_p2.m_x, 4);
        myfile.write((char*)&it->m_p2.m_y, 4);
        myfile.write((char*)&it->m_p2.m_z, 4);

        //p3 coordinates
        myfile.write((char*)&it->m_p3.m_x, 4);
        myfile.write((char*)&it->m_p3.m_y, 4);
        myfile.write((char*)&it->m_p3.m_z, 4);

        myfile.write(attribute,2);
    }

    myfile.close();
}
```

Where `tri` is just a structure for a triangle containing the 3 points and the normal as "3D vectors" (i.e. Structures with x,y,z, value) ...

Comment: _"The header needs to be written in the ascii mode"_ noo

Answer (score 8):

The size argument to `write()` is the size in bytes, not in bits. You are passing 32 for a `float` when you should be passing 4.

Comment: That is why using `sizeof(variable_name)` is the suggested method

Comment: thanks! i see ... actually I did not use size of, because I expect the size to be smaller than the actual space that needs to be filled for writing. If I do not use the exact bytes, the file cannot be read properly afterwards.